# Почему создается пустая миграция SQLite в EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Ну, собственно, сабж.
Установленные пакеты:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

Содержимое AppContext:

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users;

    public DbSet<Film> Films;

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
       => options.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=.\Data\blogging.db");
}
```

Есть две модели `Film.cs` и `User.cs`.
Когда пишу команду `Add-Migration InitialCreate` создается пустая миграция. Ну и естественно после `Update-Database` создается пустая бд с одной таблицей `__EFMigrationsHistory`.
Почему так?

Comment: `public DbSet<User> Users;` - это поле. Замените поля на свойства: `public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }`

Comment: @alexander-petrov    Спасибо, так заработало( ну почти). Но почему без этих пустых автосвойств не работало?

Comment: Потому что EF ищет и использует именно свойства.

Comment: Оформите комментарий в ответ, я отмечу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`public DbSet<User> Users;` - это поле. Замените поля на свойства:
`public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }`

Дело в том, что EF ищет и использует именно свойства.